# Return query results in same order as the values in my `IN(....)` statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select users from my database with the "IN" statement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id IN ("20,24,23,26,27,28,25")
```

...this works but i need exactly this order (20,24,23,26,27,28,25) for my output. PHP orders the ids by DESC or ASC  ... how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Side note: it's not PHP that does that in this case, it's mySQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just use `FIELD()` in the `ORDER BY` clause

```
ORDER BY FIELD(user_id, 20, 24, 23, 26, 27, 28, 25) ASC
```

- [MySQL FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)